# how to calculate different number of days a date column has

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe that has multiple rows with many dates.How to calculate number of rows matching a date and number of unique dates we have :

```
linear_acceleration 2017-06-29 07:47:21
gravity 2017-06-29 07:47:21
pressure 2017-06-30 07:47:22
heart_rate 2017-07-01 07:47:22
magnetometer 2017-07-02 07:47:22
```

Comment: You should post the text output from dput(head(dfrm)) as an [edit] to your question body. The answer might derived from table(dfrm$date_col)

Comment: dput is very elaborate for my data frame, which is just not helping. I tried several times.

Comment: That makes no sense.  dput should work for any datafry and head is just the first 6 rows.

Comment: Ok, I will try to include it tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dates are all in a single column called `date` and your data frame is called `df` you can do this:

```r
length(table(substr(as.character(df$date), 1, 10)))
```

to get the number of unique dates.

If you have a date called `test_date` you wish to match and you want to work in base R you can do:

```
which(substr(as.character(df$date), 1, 10) == as.character(test_date))
```